# Dynamic dimensions in Cloudwatch Alarms using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to create cloudwatch alarms using Terraform.

I'm trying to build alarms based on variables.

I'm trying to do it like this...

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "global_alarms" {
count               = length(var.alarms)
alarm_name          = "america- 
america-${var.alarms[count.index].component}-${var.alarms[count.index].metric_name}"
comparison_operator = "${var.alarms[count.index].comparison_operator}"
evaluation_periods  = "2"
metric_name         = "${var.alarms[count.index].metric_name}"
namespace           = "${var.alarms[count.index].namespace}"
period              = "120"
statistic           = "${var.alarms[count.index].statistic}"
threshold           = "${var.alarms[count.index].threshold}"
dimensions          = {
     var.alarms[count.index].dimensions.keys[0] = 
     var.alarms[count.index].dimensions.values[0]
   }
alarm_description   = "${var.alarms[count.index].alarm_description}"
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "alarms" {
type    = list(object({
component               = string
comparison_operator     = string
metric_name             = string
namespace               = string
statistic               = string
threshold               = string
dimensions              = object({
    keys        = list(string)
    values      = list(string)
})
alarm_description       = string
}))

default = [{
  component = "Clickhouse"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  metric_name = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace = "AWS/EC2"
  statistic = "Maximum"
  threshold = "80"
  dimensions = {
      keys = ["InstanceId"]
      values = ["i-01f4a87e824xxx"]
  }
  alarm_description = "america america"
 }]
}
```

This doesn't work if I want to create two alarms using the same resource that have different dimensions.

The problem is here

```
dimensions          = {
 var.alarms[count.index].dimensions.keys[0] = 
 var.alarms[count.index].dimensions.values[0]
}
```

How do I acheive this. Please help.

Comment: The `for_each` meta-argument probably makes most sense: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each